# Hidden fields of complex object not passing to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the HTML helper `HiddenFor` inside of a `for` loop to bind some properties of a complex object back to my model.

If I interrogate the view, I can see the values are being set correct in the hidden fields, but when I submit my form, the values are null in the controller.

**VIEW**

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CustomerSearchResponses.customers.Count; i++)
 {
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerSearchResponses.customers[i].name.first)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerSearchResponses.customers[i].name.last)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerSearchResponses.customers[i].name.company)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerSearchResponses.customers[i].address.line1)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerSearchResponses.customers[i].address.line2)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerSearchResponses.customers[i].address.city)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerSearchResponses.customers[i].address.stateProvince)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerSearchResponses.customers[i].address.postalCode)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerSearchResponses.customers[i].address.country)
  }

<input id="CustomerSearchResponses_customers_0__name_first" name="CustomerSearchResponses.customers[0].name.first" type="hidden" value="BRIAN">
```

**MODEL**

```
    public class RequestViewModel
{
    **some other props**
    public CustomerSearchResponse CustomerSearchResponses { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult QASAddress(RequestViewModel model, string previousButton, string submitButton)
{
// Do Stuff 
}
```

**Hidden Fields**
[image]

Not all hidden fields are posted here for the sake of length, but they are all setting correctly. When I POST my form, the `CustomerSearchResponses.customers[i]` object is there, but the `name` and `address` objects are null.

Comment: could you post view model structure, also signature of controller action to which you are posting to

Comment: Also post an example of the HTML page source once the view has been rendered, showing the hidden fields.

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: Thank you @DevNoob. Your code snippet for RequestViewModel has the property "CustomerSearchResponse" but your view is refering CustomerSearchResponses (plural form). could you try replacing CustomerSearchResponse with collection of CustomerSerarchResponses.

Comment: @sam I apologize, that was likely a typo when I was desperately trying to figure out a solution. The property names do indeed match, and I have updated the property in my question to match.

Comment: @DevNoob I know its silly to ask, hope you have placed HiddenFor tags within <form> but not outside form.

Comment: @sam not silly, but yes the HiddenFor tags are inside of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample application with GET and POST actions in a controller and I see customer properties in POST as shown below:[image]